# How to debug this error while logging into facebook integrated with android?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

What is this error when i login to facebook?
Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you don't have the Facebook application installed on your simulator / phone.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) you can read on how to install the Facebook application on your simulator.